# Add a Bearer Token to a Breezejs fetchMetadata Call

Tags: breeze, openid-connect

My breeze services works great.  But I just moved it behind a WSO2 API Manager.  It now needs a Bearer Token for each call.

I have the Bearer Token.  But I can't seem to figure out how to add it to the Metadata Call.

I tried something like this.  But it did not add a header to the metadata call:

```
    var ajaxAdapter: any = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');

    ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = {
        headers: {
            "X-Test-Header": "foo2"
        }
    }
```

Does the fetchMetadata use a different system from the ajax adapter?

**How can I add a header to the Fetch Metadata call?**

Comment: Are you able to add the header to regular query calls?  How is that configured?

Comment: @SteveSchmitt - Hmm, no, it is not adding it to the normal calls.  The docs say this is the way to do it.  But it does not work...  Sounds like I need to do more digging.

Comment: What other client-side libraries are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I was using the Fetch API.  So I had to do it that way.  Here is what my setup looks like:

```
setupFetchClient() {
    let httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.configure(config => {

        config.withDefaults({
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            }
        })
        .withInterceptor({
            request(request: Request) {
                let accessToken = getAccessToken();
                request.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
                return request;
            },
            responseError(error) {
                return error;
            }
        })
        .useStandardConfiguration();
    });

    // Aurelia Specific Code.
    Container.instance.registerInstance(HttpClient, httpClient);
}
```